# Python 3.2: TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method

Tags: python-3.x

**Basically I copied these methods from stackoverflow and modified them for my necessity:**

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection, HTTPSConnection
import select
connections = {}


def request(method, url, body=None, headers={}, **kwargs):
    scheme, _, host, path = url.split('/', 3)
    h = connections.get((scheme, host))
    if h and select.select([h.sock], [], [], 0)[0]:
        h.close()
        h = None
    if not h:
        Connection = HTTPConnection if scheme == 'http:' else HTTPSConnection
        h = connections[(scheme, host)] = Connection(host, **kwargs)
    h.request(method, '/' + path, body, headers)
    return h.getresponse()


def urlopen(url, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    resp = request('POST' if data else 'GET', url, data, *args, **kwargs)
    if resp.status == 400:
        fileAccessed = resp.read()
        if 'failed to open stream: Permission denied' in str(fileAccessed):
            return "permission denied"
        else:
            return fileAccessed
    else:
        return "not found"
```

**And now I use them similar to this example:**

```
with open('addons.txt', 'r') as addonsFile:
    for line in addonsFile:
        addon = line.rstrip()
        fileUrl = 'http://www.google.com/%s/ncr' % addon
        response = urlopen(fileUrl)
```

**The program gets the first addon and makes the first request fine. At the second iteration, I get this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/add.py", line 45, in <module>
    response = urlopen(fileUrl)
  File "/root/add.py", line 26, in urlopen
    resp = request('POST' if data else 'GET', url, data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/add.py", line 15, in request
    if h and select.select([h.sock], [], [], 0)[0]:
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

**Dear lords of stackoverflow, please help me correct my program!**

Comment: What is `h.sock` when it fails?  Try printing it and its `type()`.

Comment: I have no idea how to print it. I've just learned python yesterday. I tried putting     print(type(h.sock))
    print(h.sock) before the "if h and select..." line but I get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sock'

Comment: What are you trying to do that Python isn't already capable of handling on its own?

Comment: I mostly use this for fileAccessed = resp.read() ... It's very important to get the full response when error 400 is returned. The full response hides something that I need.

Comment: Guys... can you please help me?

Comment: No'one ever answered to the questions that I asked on this website. NEVER... I had another account before this one and I always got no answers. Why do I keep trying... ? :(

Comment: @RobertCalceanu This question isn't in the correct format for this site. If you want your questions answered, you should do some more research and understand exactly what you need help with. Posting code and an error without any explanation as to what is trying to be accomplished will rarely get you an answer, and even more rarely a useful one. If you can post an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, people would be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... so... I don't know...
I deleted the part where I got the error:

```
  if h and select.select([h.sock], [], [], 0)[0]:
        h.close()
        h = None
    if not h:
```

and now everything works.

Comment: I deleted these two lines as well:
import select
h = connections.get((scheme, host))